# which subnet i can use for 51. and 62

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, ipv4

I want to use subnet which covers

62.0.0.0  and 51.0.0.0  but not 10.1.1.0/24.

The problem is my gateway is like 62.14.33.222 and ip is 51.33.11.11.

Now i need to select subnet which cover both. ANy idea

i want something like /1, /2

Comment: These are public IP addresses, and thus you should not be playing with them. Take a step back, think about what you're trying to achieve and then update your question with more details.

Comment: It looks like the smallest subnet that will cover 51.* and 62.* is 48.0.0.0/4

Comment: @FrankThomas when i use /2, i get error that it overlaps with 10.1.1.1

Comment: @FrankThomas 51 => 0011 0011 (0x33), 62 => 0011 1110 (0x3E)... /4 is the smallest. Don't strip the leading zeroes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are public IP addresses, and thus you should not be playing with them. Take a step back, think about what you're trying to achieve and then update your question with more details.

In addition to these being public IPs, using addresses that are so far apart means you should probably be routing between them, not adjusting your netmask... whatever you're doing, it's probably not going to work.

---

To answer your question bluntly (and hopefully impart some understanding of subnets):

The IP is represented in decimal, but netmasks are a '*number of bits that must match*', so you need to be comfortable with converting decimal to binary.

```
    62    .     14    .     33    .    222
0011 1110   0000 1110   0010 0001   1101 1110
```

```
    51    .     33    .     11    .     11
0011 0011   0010 0001   0000 1011   0000 1011
```

We can now take the two binary addresses, and look for when the first bit is different:

```
0011 1110   0000 1110   0010 0001   1101 1110
0011 0011   0010 0001   0000 1011   0000 1011
     ^
```

As the 5th bit is the first that is different, your netmask will need to be:

```
1111 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
   240    .     0     .     0     .     0
```

Often represented as `x.x.x.x/4` (four leading `1`s, followed by all `0`s).

---

When a computer is trying to determine if it can directly access a remote host, it uses the netmask. Below we are doing bit-wise AND operation, and then comparing them.

```
if ((local_addr AND netmask) == (remote_addr AND netmask)) {
    /* access directly */
} else {
    /* access via router */
}
```

#### Scenario #1 (netmask `/4`):

```
local address:   0011 1110   0000 1110   0010 0001   1101 1110
network mask:    1111 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
                -----------------------------------------------
local network:   0011 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
```

```
remote address:  0011 0011   0010 0001   0000 1011   0000 1011
network mask:    1111 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
                -----------------------------------------------
remote network:  0011 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
```

Local and Remote networks match, access directly.

#### Scenario #2 (netmask `/5`):

```
local address:   0011 1110   0000 1110   0010 0001   1101 1110
network mask:    1111 1000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
                -----------------------------------------------
local network:   0011 1000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
```

```
remote address:  0011 0011   0010 0001   0000 1011   0000 1011
network mask:    1111 1000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
                -----------------------------------------------
remote network:  0011 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000   0000 0000
```

Local and Remote networks *do not* match, access via router.